# Build an object comment tree

Tags: php, mysql, object

I want to make comment system with limited replies.
For instance:

```
#1st comment
## reply to the 1st comment
## reply to the 1st comment
#2nd comment
#3rd comment
## reply to the 3rd comment
```

So there is one reply tree for the each comment.
And in the end I'd like to use it like that, assuming I have in $comments array of objects from db:

```
foreach($comments as $comment)
{
    echo $comment->text;

    if($comment->childs)
    {
        foreach($comment->childs as $child)
        {
            echo $child->text;
        }
    }
}
```

So I guess I need to create another object but don't know how to make it all work. Should I use stdClass or something else?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms I try to lay down the problem to understand it and see what type of OO design rises from there. As far as I can see it looks like you have three identifiable objects: the object to comment on, the first level comment and the second level ones.

- The object to comment on has a list of first level comments.
- First level comments can in turn have child comments.
- Second level comments can't have childs.

So you can start by modeling that:

```
class ObjectThatCanHaveComments
{
     protected $comments;
     ...
     public function showAllComments()
     {
         foreach ($this->comments as $comment)
         {
            $comment->show();
         }
     }
}

class FirstLevelComment
{
     protected $text;
     protected $comments;
     ...
     public function show()
     {
         echo $this->text;
         foreach ($this->comments as $comment)
         {
            $comment->show();
         }
     }
}

class SecondLevelComment
{
     protected $text;

     public function show()
     {
         echo $this->text;
     }
}
```

That could be a valid first approach. If this works for your problem you could improve it by creating a [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to model the comments, and thus remove the duplicated code of traversing the list of comments and the `$text` definition. Note that the comment classes are already polymorphic in the `show()` message.